# Filter by hour in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I filter a DataFrame indexed by datetime so that I get only the entries within certain hours of every day?

I am looking for something equivalent to the following `R` code for an `xts` object

```
df["09:00:00::17:00:00"]
```

Comment: Would `dt.between_time("9:00", "17:00")`, as done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179214/selecting-data-between-specific-hours-in-a-pandas-dataframe), work for your purposes?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I did not catch that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want the `between_time` method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html#pandas.DataFrame.between_time

Comment: you could also group the data by passing a function that groups the data based on the hours you desire and the use the filter method on the resulting groupby object.

Answer (score 6):

Hope this helps: `df[(df.Time > '08:00') & (df.Time < '08:05')]`