# How do you isolate the rows in a DataFrame that are between two times for an if statement?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with data for each hourly period for a year, and I would like to create a new row with a zero in all the rows that are between 9:00 and 17:00 and in that same row add the data from another row if it is not in this time range

I believe that I want something like;

```
if '9.00' >= final_df.index <= '17.00':
    do some action
else
    do another action
```

This is not yet working, the first reason is that at the moment it is missing the full date. Is there some way I can get around that? The first line sort of works if I use;

```
if '2017-10-16 9.00' >= final_df.index <= '2017-10-16 17.00':
```

Is there a way I can get around this.

For reference the first 5 data points are;

```
                       A    B       C   D   E
Timestamp                   
2017-10-15 13:30:00 59.9    17.14   0   1   0
2017-10-15 14:30:00 64.3    17.22   0   1   0
2017-10-15 15:30:00 68.6    17.18   0   1   0
2017-10-15 16:30:00 77.6    17.08   0   1   0
2017-10-15 17:30:00 74.5    16.93   0   1   0
```

Comment: What is the "action" you are trying to do? The solution may (or may not) depend on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting Data between Specific hours in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179214/selecting-data-between-specific-hours-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @coldspeed is that better?

Comment: Almost... what is the expected result?

Comment: @Georgy I don't think so, cause I don't think I can use .between_time for this, but I may be wrong

Comment: @coldspeed So I basically want a copy of the contents of column D, but I want all rows between 9 and 17 to equal 0, I think I can work it out given the answer posted below. Thanks

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic Shorter alternatives are possible. Give me a second and I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DatetimeIndex.hour`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html) to create a mask that you could use on your `DataFrame`. For your given data, let's just say that the region of interest is that between 15 and 17, and that you want to sum `A` in the region and `B` outside. You would do that through something like the following:

```
In [100]: mask = (df.index.hour > 14) & (df.index.hour < 17)

In [101]: df[mask].A.sum()
Out[101]: 146.2

In [102]: df[~mask].B.sum()
Out[102]: 51.29
```

Edit: The task that was now added to the question happens to also be readily solvable with this approach; assuming that the column of interest is `B`:

```
In [117]: df['Result'] = ~mask * df.B

In [118]: df
Out[118]:
                        A      B  C  D  E  Result
Timestamp
2017-10-15 13:30:00  59.9  17.14  0  1  0   17.14
2017-10-15 14:30:00  64.3  17.22  0  1  0   17.22
2017-10-15 15:30:00  68.6  17.18  0  1  0    0.00
2017-10-15 16:30:00  77.6  17.08  0  1  0    0.00
2017-10-15 17:30:00  74.5  16.93  0  1  0   16.93
```